# How to properly implement INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Tags: wpf, inotifydataerrorinfo

I'm a little confused by [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee652637%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

It's not clear how to treat and set entity realted errors.

Code in example:

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || 
        !errors.ContainsKey(propertyName)) return null;
    return errors[propertyName];
}
```

but documentation for GetErrors() states:

> propertyName - The name of the property to retrieve validation errors
>   for; **or null or Empty, to retrieve entity-level errors**.

Another example suggests just returning _errors.Values of the dictionary. And this is just all properties errors but again not entity errors.

Comment: "Entity-Level" appears to be a term which describes a "Generic" error (not pertaining to a particular property). This error could be related to Many or All properties, or it could pertain to No particular property (perhaps the internal state was corrupted).

Comment: [How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/21970328)

Answer (score 2):

As per the "Remarks" section from the documentation: [MSDN: INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee652637%28v=vs.95%29.aspx/)

> This interface enables data entity classes to implement custom
>   validation rules and expose validation results asynchronously. This
>   interface also supports custom error objects, multiple errors per
>   property, cross-property errors, and entity-level errors.
>   Cross-property errors are errors that affect multiple properties. You
>   can associate these errors with one or all of the affected properties,
>   or you can treat them as entity-level errors. Entity-level errors are
>   errors that either affect multiple properties or affect the entire
>   entity without affecting a particular property.

I might suggest that the implementation of `GetErrors` is highly dependent upon your error handling scheme. If, for instance, you do not intend to support `Entity-Level` errors, then your example code is sufficient. If, however, you do need to support `Entity-Level` errors, then you may handle the `IsNullOrEmpty` condition separately:

```
Public IEnumerable GetErrors(String propertyName)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        return entity_errors;
    if (!property_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        return null;
    return property_errors[propertyName];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I haven't found an proper answer here my solution, all validation errors are returned when the value is null or empty:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>> modelErrors = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>>();

public bool HasErrors { get => modelErrors.Any(); }

public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
    {
        return modelErrors.Values.SelectMany(x => x);   // return all errors
    }
    modelErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var propertyErrors);
    return propertyErrors;
}
```