# Set errors from code to xaml after calling a post method

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, endpoint

I'm using ValidationRules in my xaml forms like this

```
      <TextBox Name="email">
            <TextBox.Text>
                  <Binding Path="email" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                              <local:NotEmptyString  ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                  </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
      </TextBox>
```

In code, before my transaction begins i check for errors like this

```
email.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();

if (Validation.GetHasError(item))
      return false;
```

I have classes that inherit ValidationRule for every validation i need, and this works fine.

But now, i need to call a post method and that method returns me an JSON error when the email already exists, I want to show that error as a validation error. is there a way to set the error to the TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to this quite unflexible binding validation, then the simplest solution would be to use `Binding.ValidatesOnException`:

```
<TextBox Name="email">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="email" 
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
             ValidatesOnException="True">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:NotEmptyString  ValidationStep="RawProposedValue" />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Then validate your JSON response:

```
class ViewModel
{
  public string Email { get; set; }

  private ValidateJsonResponse(Json jsonObject)
  {
    if (!JsonIsValid(jsonObject))
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Email already exists.");
    }
  }
}
```

But since exceptions can have some impact on the performance, you generally should avoid them. You can argue, if failed input validation is a good reason to throw an exception. I doubt it is.

Alternatively implement a second `ValidationRule` and trigger the binding to execute it. You must find a way to access the JSON response to check whether it is valid or not. Since the `ValidationRule` is instantiated in the XAML and can't have a `DependencyProperty` to allow binding, this could be slightly complicated. That's why binding validation is not very flexible. The `ValidationRule` instance of the binding is quite isolated from the rest of the code e.g., the view model.

The recommended pattern is to have your view model implement he `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface. See this post for an example or links regarding the implementation: [How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792)