# validation with validation rules in WPF on button click

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a view with a standard validation rule. It works as expected, if I tpye some text in the field, and then delete it, error icon and text are showing. Now, I would like to have the logic, if the user clicks the save button, the validation rule triggers if the field is empty. I have found on the net solutions with XAML codebehind, but I would like to have it in a proper MVVM pattern. Is this even possible? If yes, how to do that?

This is the viewmodel:

```
public class CapacityTypeViewModel
{
    private readonly AppDataContext _appDataContext;
    private readonly CapacityTypeService _capacityTypeService;

    // commands
    public UICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    // model
    private CapacityTypeModel _capacityType;
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public CapacityTypeViewModel(AppDataContext appDataContext)
    {
        _appDataContext = appDataContext;
        _capacityTypeService = new CapacityTypeService(_appDataContext);

        SaveCommand = new UICommand(SaveCapacity, CanSave);

        _capacityType = new CapacityTypeModel();

        Type = _capacityType.Type;
    }

    private void SaveCapacity()
    {
        _capacityTypeService.Save(Type);
        ThemedMessageBox.Show("Kapacitástípus", "A kapacitástípus sikeresen mentésre került", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

    private bool CanSave() => true;
}
```

And this is the related part of the view:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <dxb:ToolBarControl UseWholeRow="True" AllowQuickCustomization="False">
        <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Mentés" Glyph="{dx:DXImage 'SvgImages/Save/Save.svg'}" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                           IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=container, Path=(dxe:ValidationService.HasValidationError), Converter={dxmvvm:BooleanNegationConverter}}"></dxb:BarButtonItem>
    </dxb:ToolBarControl>
    <dxlc:LayoutControl Name="container" Grid.Row="1" dxe:ValidationService.IsValidationContainer="True">
        <dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Kapacitástípus" LabelPosition="Top">
                <dxe:TextEdit Name="tbCapacityType">
                    <Binding Path="Type" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <Helpers:RequiredValidationRule FieldName="Kapacitástípus"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </dxe:TextEdit>
            </dxlc:LayoutItem>
        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
    </dxlc:LayoutControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Simply use an `ICommand` bound to the `Button`. This command then executes the `ValidationRule`.

Comment: Yes, but how? In every article, what I read, the solution is with codebehind. Maybe I'm searching the wrong terms. Do you have maybe some hints for me?

Comment: Can you show your view model, please? Also the way you are currently handling the save button?

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply invoke the validation rule before executing the command.

You should always let the binding source i.e. your view model implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples) to avoid bad performance and memory leaks.

It's also recommended to validate the view model by implementing [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792) rather than using binding validation.

The following example validates on exception to keep the example simple. As noticed before it's recommended to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` instead of throwing exceptions. Exception generally have a negative performance impact.

```
public class CapacityTypeViewModel
{
    public ICommand SaveCommand => new UICommand(SaveCapacity, CanSave);

    public string Type { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<string, ValidationRule> ValidationRules { get; }

    public CapacityTypeViewModel(AppDataContext appDataContext)
    {
        _appDataContext = appDataContext;

        this.ValidationRules = new Dictionary<string, ValidationRule> 
        { 
            { nameof(this.Type), new RequiredValidationRule {FieldName = "Kapacitástípus"} } 
        };        
    }

    private void SaveCapacity()
    {
        if (!this.ValidationRules.TryGetValue(nameof(this.Type), out Validationrule rule)
          || !rule.Validate(this.Type, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).IsValid)
        {
            // Notify the view (via the data binding) about the validation error.
            // Requires the Binding to enable Binding.ValidatesOnException.
            // Consider to let the view model implement INotifyDataErrorInfo instead of throwing exceptions.
            throw new ArgumentException(rule.ErrorContent as string);
        }

        _capacityTypeService.Save(Type);
        ThemedMessageBox.Show("Kapacitástípus", "A kapacitástípus sikeresen mentésre került", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

    private bool CanSave() => true;
}
```

**View**

```
<dxe:TextEdit Name="tbCapacityType">
  <Binding Path="Type"  
           ValidatesOnExceptions="True" 
           UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
</dxe:TextEdit>
```