# How do you trigger UpdateSource from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

In `UI` you can do this;

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
   MyTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

But with binding `Command`, how do you do that? For example, I have the following;

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox">
   <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding
         Mode="TwoWay"
         Path="MyTextBoxDataBinding"
         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <validations:MyTextBoxValidation ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
         </Binding.ValidationRules>
       </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<Button Command="{Binding Path=UpdateSourceNow}"/>
```

and assuming in my `ViewModel` I have this;

```
private string? _MyTextBoxDataBinding = string.Empty;
public string? MyTextBoxDataBinding{
    get => _MyTextBoxDataBinding;
    set { SetProperty(ref _MyTextBoxDataBinding, value); }
}
...

private readonly MyButtonCommand _UpdateSourceNow;
public ICommand UpdateSourceNow => _UpdateSourceNow;
private void UpdateSourceNowFunction(object commandParamater){
   //update the source of MyTextBoxDataBinding and notify UI
}

public MyViewModel(){
   _UpdateSourceNow= new MyButtonCommand(UpdateSourceNowFunction);
}
```

I have a `ValidationRule` in my `TextBox` which validates an empty value, it also shows an error message below the TextBox but I don't want it to be shown at the first load of the `Window`. Now, on the Button `Click`, the `ValidationRule` should be triggered. But it seems the only way to trigger it if the TextBox is never been touched is by updating the source. But how can I do this in my ViewModel so I don't have to do it directly on the UI?

Also, I have a `DataGrid` and the generated columns contain `TextBoxes`. I'd like to set the same `ValidationRule` so it should worth doing this in `ViewModel` instead of the UI.

Comment: You should consider instead of getting the information from the UI, to get the information from the data behind. Imagine you have a datagrid with 10 million of rows, it would need to load every UI element to render the every single row. Which isn’t really a light operation.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do is; On `Button_Click`, make sure all the `TextBox` added on the `DataGrid` has a value. I also have a `ValidationRule` on the `TextBox` which generates a text error in those TextBoxes, the `ValidationRule` should be triggered with the above method.

Comment: I also have an `ICommand` bind into the `Button`, but I couldn't find a way to trigger my `ValidationRule` from my `ViewModel`. Anyway, my `DataGrid` is allowed only to have 50 items.

Comment: To validate your view model, you should always prefer to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo over binding validation. This enables property validation e.g. on property changes directly in the view model: [How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792)