# WPF validation property existence in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to understand how a `TextBox` element/class in WPF can have the `validation` property e.g. in the code below that is in every tutorial I follow

```xml
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20">
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

From what I understand, `Trigger` will track the value of `Validation.HasError` property of `TextBox`. However, I looked into the source code of `TextBox` and its parent classes, and nowhere there is a `Validation` property defined. So how does it exist in `TextBox`? I saw that `TextBox` and `Validation` classes are inside the same namespace `System.Windows.Controls`. Does that have anything to do with this?

And just to check my understanding, if I implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in a view model, then the `Validation` class of Microsoft (which I can't decompile) would internally track the `ErrorsChanged` event and set its `HasError` property to equal my implementation of `HasErrors` from the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` e.g. it would do something like this:

```
 public Validation(...){
              ...
              Errors += ErrorsChanged
              ...
         }
         private void Errors()
         {
              ...
              HasError = myImplementationOfINotifyDataErrorInfo.HasErrors
         }
```

or maybe

```
 public Validation(...){
              ...
         }
          public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            name: "HasError",
            propertyType: typeof(bool),
            ownerType: typeof(Validation),
            typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ErrorsChanged));
         }
```

Am I right? For some reason I seem to can't open `Validation` class; I tried `go to implementation` in Visual Studio but it says it can't find the file.

Comment: [Validation.HasError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation.haserror?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is an attached property. In Visual Studio you can always move the cursors on a type and then press F1 to navigate to the documentation of this class. To change the visual error feedback, you must define a corresponding DataTemplate. See [How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792) to learn more. Validation is managed by the binding engine.

Comment: @BionicCode Yes I went to the docs but it's not documented there. Is there a list or a way to see attached properties on a class?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Validation is a static class that defines a set of attached properties. This properties are then read by the binding engine. Follow the above link to get a quick understanding on how property validation works. There no real logic in the Validation class. It just allows to set and get validation related values element specific (attached properties). The logic, the code that invokes those properties, is deep inside the binding engine of WPF. The binding engine will lookup a INotifyDataErrorInfo interface and subscribe to the ErrorsChanged event. Follow the link

Comment: "The logic, the code that invokes those properties is deep inside the binding engine of WPF" Yes I was looking for that, but it seems I won't be able to see that. I just want to make sure I totally understand everything and know what's possible.

Comment: INotifyDataErrorInfo works exactly like INotifyPropertyChanged. Binding engine will lookup the interface, subscribe to the event to track changes. You must take a look in the source code browser. But it won't help you to solve your problem on how to customize the visual error feedback as this is done via the API. For this you must consult the .NET API documentation as suggested before. The 2nd link that I've provided also gives you an idea about how the validation works and how to implement and use the interface properly. Based on your questions you should understand the API first.

Comment: Attached Property are created in a separate class from the object class they are attached to.
That is why they are «Attached».
The most common examples are Grid.Row/Column and Canvas.Top/Left/Botton/Right.
Validation is a class containing several of these properties.
See documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: The 2nd link also shows how to customize the error feedback.

Comment: Or follow this link [Data validation (data binding overview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#data-validation) (it does give you useful information, but does not show how to implement  the interface for property validation. It's focused on binding validation but it will show how to define the error template).

Comment: From Sharp's point of view, Attached Properties are DependencyProperty registered via the RegisterAttached method. Also, by convention, Set/GetNameProperty methods are added to the Attached Property to facilitate programming. There is no Set method for read-only properties.
In Visual Studio, you can jump to their description by typing `Validation.GetHasError` or `Validation.HasErrorProperty`  in some method's code  and pressing F12.