# How to handle dialogs following the MVVM design pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

I'm using Material Design for WPF to show a dialog which receives some inputs from the user, and I would like to return a value when it's closed. Here is the sample code:

**VM's method that opens the dialog**

```csharp
private async void OnOpenDialog()
{
    var view = new TakeInputDialogView();
    
    var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ClosingEventHandler);
}
```

**Dialog's VM code**

```csharp
public class TakeSomeInputDialogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _name, value);
            SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsNameInvalid => CanSave();

    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; }

    public TakeSomeInputDialogViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSave, CanSave);
    }

    private void OnSave()
    {
        DialogHost.Close("RootDialog");
    }

    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name);
    }
}
```

When the user clicks save I would like to return Name or some object that will be constructed depending on the user's input.

Side note: I'm also using Prism library, but decided to go with Material Design dialog because I can't locate the dialog in a correct place, when I open the dialog via prism I could only open it in the center of screen or in the center of owner, but I have a single window which hosts sidebar, menu control and content control, and I need to open the dialog in the middle of content control which I wasn't able to achieve.

P.S: I could bind the **DataContext** of the Dialog to the VM that opens it, but I might have many dialogs and the code might grow too big.

Comment: You seem to have created a problem out of nothing here.  Why ( oh WHY ) would you have many dialogs in a given view?

Comment: For example, one dialog for creating a user, another one for is updating/viewing details of the user, one for error/warning messages etc... Why would that be a problem? Is there any kind of a recommendation that limits the number of dialogs that we should stick to?

Comment: Your question is eminently reasonable and comes up all the time. Abstract design recommendations mean nothing. Useful Windows applications, including WPF applications, use dialogs ubiquitously. It absolutely can be done while honoring the MVVM pattern and @BionicCode's excellent answer provides a good roadmap for a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never show a dialog from the View Model. This is not necessary and will eliminate the benefits MVVM gives you.

### Rule of thumb

The MVVM dependency graph:

```
View ---> View Model ---> Model
```

Note that the dependencies are on application level. They are component dependencies and not class dependencies (although class dependencies derive from the constraints introduced by the component dependencies).
The above dependency graph translates to the following rules:

In MVVM the View Model does not know the View: the View is nonexistent.
Therefore, if the View is nonexistent for the View Model it is not aware of UI: the View Model is View agnostic.
As a consequence, the View Model has no interest in displaying dialogs. It doesn't know what a dialog is.
A "dialog" is an information exchange between two subjects, in this case the user and the application.
If the View Model is View agnostic it also has no idea of the user to have a dialog with.
The View Model doesn't show dialog controls nor does it handle their flow.

Code-behind is a compiler feature (`partial class`).
MVVM is a design pattern.
Because by definition a design pattern is language and compiler agnostic, it doesn't rely on or require language or compiler details.
This means a compiler feature can never violate a design pattern.
Therefore code-behind can't violate MVVM.
Since MVVM is a ***design*** pattern only ***design*** choices can violate it.

Because XAML doesn't allow to implement complex logic we will always have to come back to C# (code-behind) to implement it.

Also the most important UI design rule is to prevent the application from collecting wrong data. You do this by:
a) don't show input options that produce an invalid input in the UI. For example remove or disable the invalid items of a `ComboBox`, so taht the user can only select valid items.
b) use data validation and the validation feedback infrastructure of WPF: [implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792) to let the View signal the user that his input is invalid (e.g. composition of a password) and requires correction.
c) use file picker dialogs to force the user to provide only valid paths to the application: the user can only pick what really exists in the filesystem.

Following the above principles

- will eliminate the need of your application to actively interact with the user (to show dialogs) for 99% of all cases.
  In a perfect application all dialogs should be input forms or OS controlled system dialogs.
- ensure data integrity (which is even more important).

### Example

The following complete example shows how to show dialogs without violating the MVVM design pattern.
It shows two cases

- Show a user initiated dialog ("Create User")
- Show an application initiated dialog (HTTP connection lost)

Because most dialogs have an "OK" and a "Cancel" button or only a "OK" button, we can easily create a single and reusable dialog.
This dialog is named `OkDialog` in the example and extends `Window`.

The example also shows how to implement a way to allow the application to actively communicate with the user, without violating the MVVM design rules.
The example achieves this by having the View Model expose related events that the View can handle. For example, the View can decide to show a dialog (e.g., a message box). In this example, the View will handle a `ConnectionLost` event raised by a View Model class. The View handles this event by showing a notification to the user.

Because `Window` is a `ContentControl` we make use of the `ContentContrl.ContentTemplate` property:
when we assign a data model to the `Window.Content` property and a corresponding `DataTemplate` to the `Window.ContentTemplate` property, we can create individually designed dialogs by using a single dialog type (`OkDialog`) as content host.

This solution is MVVM conform because View and View Model are still well separated in term of responsibilities.
Every solution is fine that follows the pattern WPF uses to display validation errors (event, exception or Binding based) or progress bars (usually Binding based).

It's important to ensure that the UI logic does not bleed into the View Model.
The View Model should never wait for a user response. Just like data validation doesn't make the View Model wait for valid input.

The example is easy to convert to support the Dependency Injection pattern.

### Reusable key classes of the pattern

**DialogId.cs**

```cs
public enum DialogId
{
  Default = 0,
  CreateUserDialog,
  HttpConnectionLostDialog
}
```

**IOkDialogViewModel.cs**

```cs
// Optional interface. To be implemented by a dialog view model class
interface IOkDialogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // The title of the dialog
  string Title { get; }

  // Use this to validate the current view model state/data.
  // Return 'false' to disable the "Ok" button.
  // This method is invoked by the OkDialog before executing the OkCommand.
  bool CanExecuteOkCommand();

  // Called after the dialog was successfully closed
  void ExecuteOkCommand();
}
```

**OkDialog.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class OkDialog : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand OkCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("OkCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

  public OkDialog(object contentViewModel)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var okCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(OkDialog.OkCommand, ExecuteOkCommand, CanExecuteOkCommand);
    _ = this.CommandBindings.Add(okCommandBinding);

    this.DataContext = contentViewModel;
    this.Content = contentViewModel;

    this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
  }

  // If there is no explicit Content, use the DataContext
  private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) => this.Content ??= e.NewValue;

  // If the content view model doesn't implement the optional IOkDialogViewModel just enable the command source.
  private void CanExecuteOkCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = (this.Content as IOkDialogViewModel)?.CanExecuteOkCommand() ?? true;

  private void ExecuteOkCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

**OkDialog.xaml**

```xml
Window Height="450" Width="800"
       Title="{Binding Title}">
  <Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition /> <!-- Content row (dynamic) -->          
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Dialog button row (static) -->          
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Dynamic content -->
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <Button Content="Ok"
                  IsDefault="True"
                  Command="{x:Static local:OkDialog.OkCommand}" />
          <Button Content="Cancel"
                  IsCancel="True" /> <!-- Setting 'IsCancel' to 'true'  will automaitcally close the dialog on click -->
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Template>
</Window>
```

### Helper classes to complete the example

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
The dialog is *always* displayed from a component of the View.

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  // By creating a RoutedCommand, we conveniently enable every child control of this view to invoke the command.
  // Based on the CommandParameter, this view will decide which dialog or dialog content to load.
  public static RoutedCommand ShowDialogCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("ShowDialogCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

  // Map dialog IDs to a view model class type
  private Dictionary<DialogId, Type> DialogIdToViewModelMap { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

    // Show a notification dialog to the user when the HTTP connection is down
    mainViewModel.ConnectionLost += OnConnectionLost;

    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
     
    this.DialogIdToViewModelMap = new Dictionary<DialogId, Type>()
    {
      { DialogId.CreateUserDialog, typeof(CreateUserViewModel) }
      { DialogId.HttpConnectionLostDialog, typeof(MainViewModel) }
    };

    // Register the routed command
    var showDialogCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(
      MainWindow.ShowDialogCommand, 
      ExecuteShowDialogCommand, 
      CanExecuteShowDialogCommand);
    _ = CommandBindings.Add(showDialogCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteShowDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    => e.CanExecute = e.Parameter is DialogId;

  private void ExecuteShowDialogCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    => ShowDialog((DialogId)e.Parameter);

  private void ShowDialog(DialogId parameter)
  {
    if (!this.DialogIdToViewModelMap.TryGetValue(parameter, out Type viewModelType)
      || !this.MainViewModel.TryGetViewModel(viewModelType, out object viewModel))
    {
      return;
    }

    var dialog = new OkDialog(viewModel);
    bool isDialogClosedSuccessfully = dialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault();
    if (isDialogClosedSuccessfully && viewModel is IOkDialogViewModel okDialogViewModel)
    {
      // Because of data bindng the collected data is already inside the view model.
      // We can now notify it that the dialog has closed and the data is ready to process.
      // Implementing IOkDialogViewModel is optional. At this point the view model could have already handled
      // the collected data via the PropertyChanged notification or property setter.
      okDialogViewModel.ExecuteOkCommand();
    }
  }

  private void OnConnectionLost(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => ShowDialog(DialogId.HttpConnectionLostDialog);
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Button Content="Create User"
          Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowDialogCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{x:Static local:DialogId.CreateUserDialog}"/>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml**
The implicit `DataTemplate` for the content of the `OkDialog`.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>

  <!-- The client area of the dialog content. 
       "Ok" and "Cancel" button are fixed and not part of the client area. 
       This enforces a homogeneous look and feel for all dialogs -->
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CreateUserViewModel}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" />
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainViewModel}">
    <TextBox Text="HTTP connection lost." />
  </DataTemplate>
```

**UserCreatedEventArgs.cs**

```cs
public class UserCreatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public UserCreatedEventArgs(User createdUser) => this.CreatedUser = createdUser;

  public User CreatedUser { get; }
}
```

**CreateUserViewModel.cs**

```cs
// Because this view model wants to be explicitly notified by the dialog when it closes,
// it implements the optional IOkDialogViewModel interface
public class CreateUserViewModel : 
  IOkDialogViewModel,
  INotifyPropertyChanged, 
  INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
  // UserName binds to a TextBox in the dialog's DataTemplate. (that targets CreateUserViewModel)
  private string userName;
  public string UserName
  {
    get => this.userName;
    set
    {
      this.userName = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public string Title => "Create User";
  private DatabaseRepository Repository { get; } = new DatabaseRepository();

  bool IOkDialogViewModel.CanExecuteOkCommand() => this.UserName?.StartsWith("@") ?? false;

  void IOkDialogViewModel.ExecuteOkCommand()
  {
    var newUser = new User() { UserName = this.UserName };

    // Assume that e.g. the MainViewModel observes the Repository
    // and gets notified when a User was created or updated
    this.Repository.SaveUser(newUser);

    OnUserCreated(newUser);
  }

  public event EventHandler<UserCreatedEventArgs> UserCreated;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnUserCreated(User newUser)
    => this.UserCreated?.Invoke(this, new UserCreatedEventArgs(newUser));

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public CreateUserViewModel CreateUserViewModel { get; }
  public event EventHandler ConnectionLost;
  private Dictionary<Type, object> ViewModels { get; }
  private HttpService HttpService { get; } = new HttpService();

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.CreateUserViewModel = new CreateUserViewModel();

    // Handle the created User (optional)
    this.CreateUserViewModel.UserCreated += OnUserCreated;

    this.ViewModels = new Dictionary<Type, object> 
    { 
      { typeof(CreateUserViewModel), this.CreateUserViewModel }, 
      { typeof(MainViewModel), this }, 
    };
  }
 
  public bool TryGetViewModel(Type viewModelType, out object viewModel)
    => this.ViewModels.TryGetValue(viewModelType, out viewModel);

  private void OnUserCreated(object? sender, UserCreatedEventArgs e)
  {
    User newUser = e.CreatedUser;
  }

  private void SendHttpRequest(Uri url)
  {
    this.HttpService.ConnectionTimedOut += OnConnectionTimedOut;
    this.HttpService.Send(url);
    this.HttpService.ConnectionTimedOut -= OnConnectionTimedOut;
  }

  private void OnConnectionTimedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => OnConnectionLost();

  private void OnConnectionLost()
    => this.ConnectionLost?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empt8y);
}
```

**User.cs**

```cs
class User
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**DatabaseRepository.cs**

```cs
class DatabaseRepository
{}
```

**HttpService.cs**

```cs
class HttpService
{
  public event EventHandler ConnectionTimedOut;
}
```

Comment: This s answer is a great resource, even if a little lengthy. It gives a clear roadmap for how this can be done correctly in a generalized way. Of course there are many, many ways to do this without breaking the MVVM pattern as long as your VM code is not dependent on UI libraries. A rule of thumb I like to use is to put all VM code in a .NET Standard library with no third party dependencies (or at least none relating to UI). Then find a way to do what you want. I have yet to be unable to do what I want while operating under this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You only really need one window in a wpf application, because a window is a content control.

You can template out the entire content using an approach called viewmodel first and data templating.

That window would look like:

```
<Window ....
    Title="{Binding Title}" 
    Content="{Binding}"
        >
</Window>
```

You would then have a base window viewmodel which exposes a title property.

When you present a viewmodel to an instance of this window you'd by default just see the .ToString() of that viewmodel appear as content. To make it give you some controls you need a datatemplate.

You associate viewmodel type with control type using DataType.

Put all your markup in usercontrols. This includes your markup for mainwindow. At startup you can show an empty instance of TheOnlyWindowIneed then set datacontext asynchronously.
Then go get any data or do anything expensive you need.  Once a skeleton mainwindow is up and visible. Showing a busy indicator.

Your datatemplates would all go in a resource dictionary which is merged in app.xaml.

An example

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyBlueViewModel}">
        <local:MyBlueUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

If you now do

```
 var win = new TheOnlyWindowIneed { Content = new MyBlueViewModel() };
 win.Owner=this;
 win.ShowDialog();
```

Then you get a dialog shown which has the window that code is in as a parent. The datacontext is your MyBlueViewModel and your entire dialog is filled with a MyBlueUserControl.

You probably want Yes/No buttons and you probably want some standardised UI.

ConfirmationUserControl can look like:

```
<UserControl.....
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ConfirmationMessage}"
                      Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="Yes"
            Command="{Binding YesCommand}"
            />
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Content="No"
            Command="{Binding NoCommand}"
            />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ConfirmationViewModel would expose the usual Title, ConfirmationMessage can be Another viewmodel ( and usercontrol pair ). This is then data templated out into UI in a similar fashion.

YesCommand would be a public iCommand which is set from whatever shows the dialog. This passes in whatever logic is to happen when the user clicks Yes. If it's deleting then it has code calls a delete method. It could use a lambda and capture the context of the owning viewmodel or it could have an explicit instance of a class passed in. The latter being more unit test friendly.

The call to this dialog is at the end of some code you have in your viewmodel.

There is no code waiting for the result.

The code that would be is in yescommand.

NoCommand might just close the parent window.  By putting code that actions  the result in yes command you probably do not need to "know" in the calling code what the user chose. It's already been handled.

You might therefore decide NoCommand uses some generic window closing approach:

```
public class GenericCommands
{
    public static readonly ICommand CloseCommand =
             new RelayCommand<Window>(o =>
             {   
                 if(o == null)
                 {
                     return;
                 }
                 if(o is Window)
                 {
                     ((Window)o).Close();
                 }
             }
             );
```

That needs a reference to the window which is passed in by parameter

```
    Command="{x:Static ui:GenericCommands.CloseCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

The viewmodel still needs to somehow initiate showing the window.

You only have the one window though.  You can put code in that and initiate showing a window from the one and only window.

All you need at a minimum is a dependency property and a callback.

```
public partial class TheOnlyWindowIneed : Window
{
    public object? ShowAdialogue
    {
        get
        {
            return (object?)GetValue(ShowAdialogueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ShowAdialogueProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowAdialogueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowAdialogue",
                    typeof(object),
                    typeof(TheOnlyWindowIneed),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null
                        , new PropertyChangedCallback(ShowAdialogueChanged)
                        )
                    );
    private static void ShowAdialogueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var win = new TheOnlyWindowIneed { Content = e.NewValue };
        win.Owner = d as TheOnlyWindowIneed;
        win.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Here when you bind ShowAdialogue to a property in your viewmodel, when you set that property to an instance of a dialogue viewmodel, it should show a dialog with that viewmodel as datacontext and as explained that will be templated out into UI.

A perhaps more elegant way to handle this would be to use the pub/sub pattern and the community mvvm toolkit messenger. You can send the viewmodel you want to show in a dialogue via messenger, subscribe in mainwindow and act in that handler.

If you just want to show some info then there is another option to consider. If  all your users are using win10+ then you can easily use toast.  The toast that pops up can have buttons in it but is usually just used to show messages.

Add the nuget package Notifications.wpf

You can show toast in your mainwindow or where notifications usually pop up in win10. In mainwindow:

```
    <toast:NotificationArea x:Name="MainWindowNotificationsArea"
                            Position="BottomRight" 
                            MaxItems="3"
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
```

In a viewmodel:

```
        var notificationManager = new NotificationManager();
        notificationManager.Show(
            new NotificationContent { 
                Title = "Transaction Saved", 
                Message = $"Transaction id {TransactionId}" },
            areaName: "MainWindowNotificationsArea");
```

The view and viewmodel are totally decoupled, you don't need any reference to anything.  NotificationContent can be much richer than shown here.

I think your app might also have to target win10 as minimum O/S.