# WPF TextBox Validation using INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox, inotifydataerrorinfo

I have created a Custom TextBox control, which overrides TextBox. I have it all working perfectly and I also have validation working with an Override of OnTextChanged.

The issue I have now is that the implementation within the ViewModel has been changed, so validation is now taking place on a button click 'save' at the end of the form (using INotifyDataErrorInfo) rather than on a keystroke basis

My question is, how to I react in my CustomControl to the validation Errors being updated because I want to recolour my textbox border based on the validation result.

---

Xaml code for where my control is added to the Window:

```
<ctrl:AppTextBox ButtonCommand="{Binding AddNewWordCommand}"
                 ButtonLabel="+"
                 Label="New Word"
                 Text="{Binding NewWord, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                 x:Name="txtNewWord" />
```

---

Xaml code for my CustomControl (AppTextBox):

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:AppTextBox}"
         BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource Inter400}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource Font_Medium}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Theme_Foreground}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,8" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">

      <Setter.Value>

        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:AppTextBox}">

          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextBox_Border_Focus}" 
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="{DynamicResource Control_CornerRadius}"
                    Cursor="IBeam"
                    Focusable="False"
                    MinHeight="{DynamicResource TextBox_Height}"
                    Padding="10,2,5,2"
                    x:Name="bdrOutline" >

              <Grid>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Background="Transparent"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            x:Name="stpLayout" >

                  <Label Background="Transparent"
                         Content="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                         Focusable="False"
                         FontFamily="{DynamicResource Inter600}"
                         FontSize="12"
                         Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBox_Label_Focus}"
                         IsTabStop="False"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Visibility="{TemplateBinding LabelVisibility}"
                         x:Name="lblHeading" />

                  <ScrollViewer Background="Transparent"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                Cursor="IBeam"
                                Foreground="{DynamicResource Theme_Foreground}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Margin="3,0,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                Visibility="Visible"
                                x:Name="PART_ContentHost" >

                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                      <i:KeyTrigger Key="Return">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" />
                      </i:KeyTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                  </ScrollViewer>

                </StackPanel>

                <ContentControl Focusable="False"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="5,0"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ErrorIcon_Canvas}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                x:Name="cvsError" />

                <Button Command="{TemplateBinding ButtonCommand}"
                        Content="+"
                        Cursor="Hand"
                        Grid.Column="2"            
                        Margin="5,0"
                        Padding="10,7"
                        Style="{DynamicResource FilledSquareButton_Base}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Visibility="Visible"
                        x:Name="btnAction" />

              </Grid>

            </Border>

            <!-- List Errors Here -->
            <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBoxItem}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                                           Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}" 
                     Style="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBox}" />

          </StackPanel>

          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="ButtonIsActive" Value="False">
              <Setter TargetName="btnAction" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="HasBorder" Value="False">
              <Setter TargetName="bdrOutline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="lblHeading" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Theme_ErrorBrush}" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="Layout" Value="Inline">
              <Setter TargetName="lblHeading" Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
              <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Margin" Value="40,5,0,0" />
              <Setter TargetName="stpLayout" Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
            </Trigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="HasBorder" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True" />
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter TargetName="bdrOutline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Theme_ErrorBrush}" />
            </MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="TextFillState" Value="Empty" />
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False" />
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter TargetName="bdrOutline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Border_Empty}" />
              <Setter TargetName="lblHeading" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Label_Empty}" />
              <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="TextFillState" Value="Empty" />
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False" />
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter TargetName="bdrOutline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Border_Empty_Hover}" />
              <Setter TargetName="lblHeading" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Label_Empty_Hover}" />
            </MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="TextFillState" Value="Filled" />
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False" />
                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False" />
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter TargetName="bdrOutline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Border_Filled}" />
              <Setter TargetName="lblHeading" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Label_Filled}" />
            </MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="TextFillState" Value="Filled" />
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False" />
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter TargetName="bdrOutline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Border_Filled_Hover}" />
              <Setter TargetName="lblHeading" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Label_Filled_Hover}" />
            </MultiTrigger>


            <MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False" />
              </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Setter TargetName="bdrOutline" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Border_Focus}" />
              <Setter TargetName="lblHeading" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBox_Label_Focus}" />
            </MultiTrigger>

          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>

      </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>

  </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to get SOME validation working in my user control:

I am able to set the red border and labels by checking

```
<Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True" />
```

**BUT** I am unable to display the errors within the control, instead I have had to add a listbox to the Window, and this is not something I want to do:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBoxItem}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=txtEntry, 
                               Path=(Validation.Errors)}" 
         Style="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBox}" />
```

I have tried adding this code to my custom Control but it doesnt work for some reason:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBoxItem}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                               Path=(Validation.Errors)}" 
         Style="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBox}" />
```

And neither does this:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBoxItem}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=PART_ContentHost,
                               Path=(Validation.Errors)}" 
         Style="{DynamicResource ErrorMessagesListBox}" />
```

Comment: You can check this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792. Basically, you would have to provide an error template. Here you can customize how the validation site appears or is adorned in case of a validation error. The binding engine will handle everything for you. just define ControlTemplate and assign it to the  `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attached property (see example). My first thought when I saw your CustomTextBox was that you should not implement all that validation logic in the control and save all the extra work by implementing proper data validation in the data source.

Comment: Yeah, I dont want to actually VALIDATE in my control, all I need to do is set my textbox border and it's label to red and also show the validation errors in a label that is part of my custom control

Comment: I understood that :) The example shows how to define an error template to show the validation error message along with visual feedback. It's in the "Preparing the view" section.

Comment: You already have the INotifyDataErroInfo implemented. Next set Binding.ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors to true. And finally define the error template and assign it to the Validation.ErrorTemplate attached property - as shown in the example.

Comment: I have managed to get my borders to be set by setting ValidatesOnDataErrors=True.
The part I am missing now is the error details, I am trying to populate a label within my CustomControl, but I cannot figure out the bindings for it.

I was trying:
Content="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"

Comment: *"I am trying to populate a label within my CustomControl"* - Why can't you use an error template? Try  `Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` (assuming that the context/source is correct).

Comment: I think both binding paths will result in the selection of the same item. Hence your source must be wrong. Where is this binding defined?

Comment: you really should use an error template instead of polluting your control with all that error related elements. This makes the visual tree unnecessarily big which will impact performance.

Comment: Too bad you didn't post the complete XAML code of your custom control. This would have been really useful. I can only guess: your are talking about the ControlTemplate of your control. If this is the case then your binding source is wrong (as mentioned before). Change the source to the templated parent (becasuse you are refering from the template content to the templated control. RelativeSource.Self only points to the element that the binding is defined on. `Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelatriveSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"`.

Comment: Please, next time provide the full context, especially if bindings don't resolve or you are experiencing wrong behavior.

Comment: I have added the code for my CustomControl (AppTextBox). I have never used ErrorTemplates before so that was why I was looking at other ways to achieve my goal, but I will take a look at the link you shared and see if I can work out how to implement one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding `RelativeSource.Self` references the current element the `Binding` is defined on. But you are inside the `ControlTemplate` and want to read from the attached property of the parent type that the `ControlTemplate` is applied to. You must therefore use `RelativeSource.TemplatedParent`. And because you want to bind the `ListBox` to the error *collection* and not to the current error *item* you must not bind the `ListBox.ItemsSource` to the current item's `ValidationError.ErrorContent` property.

Define the `Binding` on the `ListBox` inside the `ControlTemplate` as follows:

```xml
<!-- List Errors Here -->
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Validation.Errors)}" 
         DisplayMemberName="ErrorContent"
         Foreground="Red" />
```

I highly recommend the use of an error `ControlTemplate` that you assign to the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attached property instead of adding error feedback visuals and logic directly to the visual tree of the default `ControlTemplate` of the control. You can follow and extend this example: [How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792).

Comment: Thank you for all your help on this. I now have this working using an ErrorTemplate :)