# When binding a textbox to an integer, check whether a valid value has been entered

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

In a WPF project, I have a text box and a button:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> <Button Content="OK" Click="ButtonClicked"/>
```

The binding of the textbox is to an integer. Here is the datacontext:

```
private int _value;
public int Value
{
  get => _value;
  set
  {
     _value = value;
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
  }
}
```

When the ok button is clicked, the value of the property is processed. Let's assume the following: The user enters a valid integer, e.g. "17". After that, he enters an invalid integers, e.g. "a". The textbox has a red border to show that this is not valid. But the value of the property is still the old value 17. If the user presses the button, the program will do its work with the value 17 (which is not displayed anymore). Because I think the red border might be overlooked or ignored and the button might be clicked anyway, the program will process a wrong value and this might lead to confusion. Hence I want to have a check whether a valid value is entered.

```
private void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(!Binding.HasAValidValue)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer");
      return;
   }

   // process the event
}
```

Do I have this possibility?

Comment: I would recommend against showing a messagebox whenever a incorrect value is entered. This would be highly disruptive to the user. A better approach is to disable buttons unless all required values are entered correctly.

Comment: This is not a graceful solution. If you want to implement property validation you should implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in the binding source. You can follow [How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792) and implement your validation rule in an extended `ValidationRule` class. The `INotifyDataErrorInfo` infrastructure will provide you with an out-of-the-box solution to show error messages and other visual feedback like a red border around the input field.

Comment: `INotifyDataErrorInfo` also declares a boolean `HasErrors` property that you can query before you use any of the validated values. I believe the example even provides a metho to check if a particular property has an error. I your case, you would check if the input is numeric using `int.TryParse`. If the parsing fails you notify the view that the property has an error. Then you don't use the property value until `INotifyDataErrorInfo.HasErrors` returns `false`.