# How do I know if a property is validated?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am coding a setting page to set the IP to an Ethernet device.

I placed a TextBox and an Apply Button in the page. After inputed the IP to the TextBox and clicking the Apply Button then set the IP to the device.

Now I need to validate the text in TextBox that if it is an IP address.

I found a tutorial in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observablevalidator#custom-validation-attributes

Here is my code:

```
public partial class EthernetConnection : ObservableObject
{
    string _IP = "";
    [IPAddress]
    public string IP {
        get => _IP;
        set { 
            if (_IP != value)
            {                    
                _IP = value;                    
                OnPropertyChanged();                           
            }
        }
    }    

    public sealed class IPAddressAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {                
            string _pattern = @"^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)$";
            if (value is string _string && Regex.IsMatch(_string, _pattern))
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }                
            return new("Failed");
        }            
    }
}
```

And it works well, when the input in TextBox is not an IP address, TextBox will prompt you.

But now I have encountered a problem. When clicking the Apply Button, I have to write additional code to recheck whether the text in the TextBox is an IP address, which is very troublesome.

Is there a way for me to directly detect if a property has been validated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soon I found another way to solve this easily in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observablevalidator

The ObservableValidator is inherit from INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=net-8.0

And there is a HasErrors property in INotifyDataErrorInfo that I can bind it with the IsEnabled property of ApplyButton.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Maybe<T>` for this rather than attributes.

```
public class Maybe<T>
{
    public class MissingValueException : Exception { }

    public readonly static Maybe<T> Nothing = new Maybe<T>();

    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.HasValue)
            {
                throw new MissingValueException();
            }
            return _value;
        }
        private set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }

    public Maybe()
    {
        HasValue = false;
    }

    public Maybe(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        HasValue = true;
    }

    public T ValueOrDefault() => this.HasValue ? this.Value : default(T);
    public T ValueOrDefault(T @default) => this.HasValue ? this.Value : @default;
    public T ValueOrDefault(Func<T> @default) => this.HasValue ? this.Value : @default();

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T v)
    {
        return v.ToMaybe();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.HasValue ? this.Value.ToString() : "()";
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Maybe<T>)
            return Equals((Maybe<T>)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Maybe<T> obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_value, obj._value)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.Equals(this.HasValue, obj.HasValue)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(_value);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.GetHashCode(this.HasValue);
        return hash;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Maybe<T> left, Maybe<T> right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Maybe<T> left, Maybe<T> right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

Then do this:

```
public partial class EthernetConnection : ObservableObject
{
    public Maybe<string> MaybeIP { get; private set; } = "";

    public string IP
    {
        set
        {
            string _pattern = @"^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)$";
            if (MaybeIP.HasValue && MaybeIP.Value != value)
            {
                MaybeIP = Regex.IsMatch(value, _pattern) ? value : Maybe<string>.Nothing;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's now like `Nullable<T>`, but for all types.

Here's some handy extension methods that make this even better:

```
public static class MaybeEx
{
    public static Maybe<T> ToMaybe<T>(this T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>(value);
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this Maybe<T> m, T @default) => m.HasValue ? m.Value : @default;
    public static T GetValue<T>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T> @default) => m.HasValue ? m.Value : @default();

    public static Maybe<U> Select<T, U>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, U> k)
    {
        return m.SelectMany(t => k(t).ToMaybe());
    }

    public static Maybe<U> SelectMany<T, U>(this Maybe<T> m, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k)
    {
        if (!m.HasValue)
        {
            return Maybe<U>.Nothing;
        }
        return k(m.Value);
    }

    public static Maybe<V> SelectMany<T, U, V>(this Maybe<T> @this, Func<T, Maybe<U>> k, Func<T, U, V> s)
    {
        return @this.SelectMany(x => k(x).SelectMany(y => s(x, y).ToMaybe()));
    }

    public static Maybe<V> Maybe<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> @this, K key) => (@this.ContainsKey(key)) ? @this[key].ToMaybe() : Maybe<V>.Nothing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to implement data validation is to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. This enables you to conveniently provide visual feedback to the user by using the built-in validation feature of the binding engine. For example, if the validation of a property fails the binding target (usually a `TextBox`) shows a red border and can even display an error message to the user.

I generally recommend to use the static `IPAddress.TryParse` or `IPAddress.Parse` methods to parse/convert the input. It's faster than using regular expression. In addition you get an `IPAddress` object as the result which is more efficient to handle than strings and can be directly used with the .NET networking API. [`IPAdress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=net-8.0) may also provide other API methods that are useful for your scenario.

I also recommend splitting your single `TextBox` up into 4 `TextBox` elements (IPv4) or 8 `TextBlock` elements (IPv6). Let the user toggle between IPv4 und IPv6 and show the correct number of `TextBox` elements respectively. I recommend creating an `Ip4TextBox` and `Ip6TextBox` to encapsulate the `TextBox` elements and their different input validation. This way toggling between the two options becomes easier.

The key is to help the user to avoid making illegal inputs e.g. too many numbers or non-numeric characters etc.
In this context you should implement a two step validation:
one raw input validation at control level, that simply checks if the input is in the correct format (for example, only allow numbers in the range of 1-255 for Ipv4).
The second (optional) validation takes place in your data model where you implement the aforementioned `INotifyDataErrorInfo` to validate that the address is semantically correct (e.g. the correct address space).
[How to add validation to view model properties or how to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608064/3141792)

## Example

The following simple example shows how to implement a `Ip4TextBox` that displays input errors to the user and does not send the input to the binding source before all errors are fixed.
The validated input value is exposed via the `IpAddress` property that only exposes valid input and is updated when the focus has left the `Ip4TextBox`.

The binding source can still implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` to further validate the input based on more specific business rules.

### Usage Example

```xml
<Window>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Ip4TextBox, Path=IpAddress}" />
  <Ip4TextBox x:Name="Ip4TextBox" />
</Window>
```

[image]

### Implementation

**Ip4TextBox.cs**

```cs
public class Ip4TextBox : Control
{
  public IPAddress IpAddress
  {
    get => (IPAddress)GetValue(IpAddressProperty);
    set => SetValue(IpAddressProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IpAddressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IpAddress",
    typeof(IPAddress),
    typeof(Ip4TextBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public int Octet1Text
  {
    get => (int)GetValue(Octet1TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(Octet1TextProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty Octet1TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Octet1Text",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(Ip4TextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(int),
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      null,
      null,
      false,
      UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus));

  public int Octet2Text
  {
    get => (int)GetValue(Octet2TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(Octet2TextProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty Octet2TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Octet2Text",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(Ip4TextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(int),
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      null,
      null,
      false,
      UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus));

  public int Octet3Text
  {
    get => (int)GetValue(Octet3TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(Octet3TextProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty Octet3TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Octet3Text",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(Ip4TextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(int),
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      null,
      null,
      false,
      UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus));

  public int Octet4Text
  {
    get => (int)GetValue(Octet4TextProperty);
    set => SetValue(Octet4TextProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty Octet4TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Octet4Text",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(Ip4TextBox),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      default(int),
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
      null,
      null,
      false,
      UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus));

  private HashSet<ValidationError> ValidationErrors { get; }
  private bool HasValidationErrors => this.ValidationErrors.Any();

  static Ip4TextBox() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Ip4TextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Ip4TextBox)));

  public Ip4TextBox()
  {
    this.ValidationErrors = new HashSet<ValidationError>();
    Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, OnValidationError);
  }

  // Commit input when the Ip4TextBox loses focus
  // and the child TextBox elements don't report any validation errors
  protected override void OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnIsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(e);
    if (!this.IsKeyboardFocusWithin
      && !this.HasValidationErrors
      && Keyboard.FocusedElement is UIElement focusedUiElement)
    {
      // Defer invocation using the dispatcher to allow the TextBox to complete event handling
      _ = Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(UpdateIpAddress, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
  }

  private void UpdateIpAddress()
  {
    string ipAddressText = string.Join('.', this.Octet1Text, this.Octet2Text, this.Octet3Text, this.Octet4Text);
    var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressText);
    this.IpAddress = ipAddress;
  }

  // Select all text
  protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);

    if (e.OriginalSource is TextBox textBox)
    {
      // Defer invocation using the dispatcher to allow the TextBox to complete event handling
      _ = Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(textBox.SelectAll, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
  }

  private void OnValidationError(object? sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
  {
    switch (e.Action)
    {
      case ValidationErrorEventAction.Added:
        _ = this.ValidationErrors.Add(e.Error);
        break;
      case ValidationErrorEventAction.Removed:
        _ = this.ValidationErrors.Remove(e.Error);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Ip4ValidationRule.cs**
The validation rule that is applied to the input by the `Ip4TextBox`.

```cs
public class Ip4ValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    => value is string inputText
      && int.TryParse(inputText, out int inputNumber)
      && inputNumber is > -1 and < 256
        ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
        : new ValidationResult(false, "Number must be within range [1-255]");
}
```

**Generic.xaml**
The default `Style` that must be added to the /Themes/Gernic.xaml file.

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:Ip4TextBox">
  <Style.Resources>
    <local:Ip4ValidationRule x:Key="Ip4ValidationRule" />

    <!-- Customizable error template that defines how the error is displayed -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplate">
      <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">

          <!-- Placeholder for the octet TextBox itself -->
          <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="AdornedElement" />
        </Border>

        <Border Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Red"
                Padding="4"
                BorderThickness="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}"
                            Foreground="Red" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!-- Input field style -->
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="50" />
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
              Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}" />
    </Style>

    <!-- Seperaetor TextBlock style -->
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="Text"
              Value="." />
      <Setter Property="FontSize"
              Value="16" />
      <Setter Property="FontWeight"
              Value="Bold" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
              Value="Bottom" />
      <Setter Property="Margin"
              Value="4,0" />
    </Style>
    <local:ValidationMultiErrorConverter x:Key="ValidationMultiErrorConverter" />
  </Style.Resources>

  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Ip4TextBox">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox Grid.Column="0">
              <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                          Path="Octet1Text"
                          NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                  <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Ip4ValidationRule" />
                  </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
              </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" />

            <TextBox Grid.Column="2">
              <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                          Path="Octet2Text"
                          NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                  <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Ip4ValidationRule" />
                  </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
              </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" />

            <TextBox Grid.Column="4">
              <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                          Path="Octet3Text"
                          NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                  <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Ip4ValidationRule" />
                  </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
              </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" />

            <TextBox Grid.Column="6">
              <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                          Path="Octet4Text"
                          NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                  <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="Ip4ValidationRule" />
                  </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
              </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
          </Grid>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```