Native XAML validation of bound object attributes
I am working on a project in C# WPF using the MVVM design pattern, which is restricted to .NET 4.8, because of old mandatory 3rd party libraries.
I have been struggling lately with user input validation, if I create a custom object, then bind the attributes of this object to textboxes Text attribute in the view like this:
class TestObject 
{
    public double DoubleValue { get; set; }
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding ViewTestObject.DoubleValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

When doing that, WPF recognize the type of the attribute (double for example) and if the user input is wrong (like 2;5), block the input or display a red border over the textbox depending of the UpdateSourceTrigger parameter value, which is what I want.
Since this behavior seemed to be natively coded, I wanted to go further by changing the IsEnabled attribute of a button according to the textboxes validation state, directly in xaml, but I can't make it work.
You can find a test project about this case in this Github repository:
https://github.com/RoosterBlueWing/TestValidationWPF
So, am I doing something wrong or is it just impossible yet?

It's not impossible but it requires putting validation logic in the view model instead so the button can also bind to the field's validation status. See if this answer or the other answers to that question help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606441/how-to-add-validation-to-view-model-properties-or-how-to-implement-inotifydataer/78686921#78686921

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79083034/13349759
You need a solution close to this. If you can't adapt it yourself, then write - I will make an implementation for you.

Thanks. I have tried both your solutions, but I can't make it work when the bindings are made to the attributes of a custom object. Since you proposed @EldHasp, I would like to see how you implement this, based on the git repository I have linked.

I adapted my code for Framework 4.8, removed everything irrelevant to the question and showed how to use it in your Solution. See my answer below.

Full working implementation for https://github.com/RoosterBlueWing/TestValidationWPF taking into account the target Framework 4.8
namespace Common
{
    public static partial class StringHelper
    {
        /// <summary>Returns a string from which the specified number of last characters have been removed.</summary>
        /// <param name="text">Original string.</param>
        /// <param name="count">Number of last characters to remove.</param>
        /// <returns>The Start of the original string without the last deleted characters.</returns>
        public static string LastRemove(this string text, int count)
        {
            if(count == 0)
                return text;
            string result = text.Remove(text.Length - count);
            return result;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace Common
{
    public static partial class VisualTreeHelper
    {
        /// <summary>Returns all children of <paramref name="parent"/>.<summary>
        /// <param name="parent">The element whose children to get.</param>
        /// <returns>A sequence listing all children.</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildren(this DependencyObject parent)
        {
            if (parent is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));

            Queue<DependencyObject> queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>(16);
            DependencyObject current = parent;
            while (true)
            {
                int count = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i));
                }

                if (queue.Count == 0)
                    break;

                current = queue.Dequeue();
                yield return current;
            }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Common
{
    public static class ValidationHelper
    {
        public static bool GetHasChildrenError(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(HasChildrenErrorProperty);
        }

        private static void SetHasChildrenError(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HasChildrenErrorPropertyKey, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HasChildrenError.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasChildrenErrorPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(nameof(HasChildrenErrorProperty).LastRemove(8), typeof(bool), typeof(ValidationHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasChildrenErrorProperty = HasChildrenErrorPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;



        public static bool GetCollectingErrors(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(CollectingErrorsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetCollectingErrors(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CollectingErrorsProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CollectingErrors.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectingErrorsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(CollectingErrorsProperty).LastRemove(8),
                                                typeof(bool),
                                                typeof(ValidationHelper),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(false)
                                                {
                                                    PropertyChangedCallback = OnCollectingErrorsChanged
                                                });

        private static ConditionalWeakTable<DependencyObject, ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>> ErroneousChildren
            = new ConditionalWeakTable<DependencyObject, ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>>();
        private static void OnCollectingErrorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (false.Equals(e.NewValue))
            {
                Validation.RemoveErrorHandler(d, OnErrorHandler);
                ErroneousChildren.Remove(d);
                d.ClearValue(ErroneousChildrenPropertyKey);
            }
            else
            {

                ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = new ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>(d.GetChildren().Where(Validation.GetHasError));
                Validation.AddErrorHandler(d, OnErrorHandler);

                if (ErroneousChildren.TryGetValue(d, out _))
                {
                    ErroneousChildren.Remove(d);
                }
                ErroneousChildren.Add(d, children);

                SetErroneousChildren(d, new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DependencyObject>(children));
                SetHasChildrenError(d, children.Count != 0);
            }
        }

        private static void OnErrorHandler(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyObject d = (DependencyObject)sender;
            DependencyObject child = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
            if (!ErroneousChildren.TryGetValue(d, out ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
            {
                if (!children.Contains(child))
                    children.Add(child);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Validation.GetHasError(child))
                {
                    int index = children.IndexOf(child);
                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        children.RemoveAt(index);
                    }
                }
            }

            SetHasChildrenError(d, children.Count != 0);
        }

        public static ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DependencyObject> GetErroneousChildren(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DependencyObject>)obj.GetValue(ErroneousChildrenProperty);
        }

        private static void SetErroneousChildren(DependencyObject obj, ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DependencyObject> value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ErroneousChildrenPropertyKey, value);
        }

        //// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ErroneousChildrenPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(nameof(ErroneousChildrenProperty).LastRemove(8),
                                                        typeof(ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DependencyObject>),
                                                        typeof(ValidationHelper),
                                                        new PropertyMetadata(new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DependencyObject>(new ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>())));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ErroneousChildrenProperty = ErroneousChildrenPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    }
}

<Window x:Class="TestValidation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestValidation"
        xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="textBoxs" common:ValidationHelper.CollectingErrors="True"
              >

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewTestObject.StringValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Grid.Row="0" Height="37" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15"/>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewTestObject.IntValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Grid.Row="1" Height="37" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15"/>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewTestObject.DoubleValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Grid.Row="2" Height="37" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15"/>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewTestObject.DecimalValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" Grid.Row="3" Height="37" FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15"/>

        </Grid>

        <Button Command="{Binding Save}" Content="Save" Grid.Row="1" Height="37" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (common:ValidationHelper.HasChildrenError), ElementName=textBoxs, Mode=OneWay}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="20" Text="{Binding (common:ValidationHelper.HasChildrenError), ElementName=textBoxs, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


If you want to do it directly in XAML, you'd have to bind to the Validation.HasError attached property of each text box on your form, then disable the button via a set of data triggers. For instance, if one of your text boxes was named MyTextBox, it would look as follows:
<Button Command="{Binding Save}" ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (Validation.HasError), ElementName=MyTextBox}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>

Then you just add more data triggers.
Of course, such a solution wouldn't be MVVM friendly, so I strongly suggest that you go the INotifyDataErrorInfo route and do your validation explicitly in the VM.

You can try adding ValidationRules, for example:
<TextBox Text="{Binding ViewTestObject.DoubleValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidationRules ={you Code}/>

